# Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013 targeting SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ssis, business-intelligence

I have VS 2013 installed with Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013.

I need to write a SSIS package to be run on SQL Server 2008 R2

Per [Analysis Services & PowerPivot Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/analysisservices/archive/2014/04/02/sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2013-ssdt-bi.aspx)
[image]

this is not officially supported.

Anyone know of a workaround to leverage VS 2013 and it's tool set.  I really thought I was done having to keep four generations of development tools on my machine... holding out hope here.

Comment: ...ended up creating a virtual machine and installing the older tools on that.  Keeping my new image clean and will dump the virtual as soon as older tools are no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. SSIS only allows a specific version of the visual studio tools (BIDS/SSDT) to work for each version of SQL Server. Each version only creates one specific SSIS Package Version.

See link here explaining.
https://sqlstudies.com/2015/04/27/what-sql-version-is-my-ssis-package/

[image]

The newest version, SSDT/Visual Studio 2015 has added backwards compatibility for SSIS finally, but only back to SQL Server 2012.

See info here in link here.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4253/backwards-compatibility-in-sql-server-data-tools-for-integration-services/

so it will not solve your problem with SQL Server 2008 R2 sorry :-(